# SSL Chat problems

Tags: java

I am developing a SSL chat and I have some problems to solve about the connection.  The console prints a connection failure. I have already done the certificates but the connection fail.

The first problem appears in the 83 line of the Class Cliente chat, that's the frame where the text is written

The code:

```
    private SSLSocketFactory factory= (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    private SSLSocket socket;
    private MensajesChat mensajes;
    private DataInputStream entradaDatos;
    private DataOutputStream salidaDatos;

    public ConexionCliente(SSLSocket socket, MensajesChat mensajes) {
        this.socket=socket;
        this.mensajes= mensajes;



        try {
            entradaDatos = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            salidaDatos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    public void run() {
        String mensajeRecibido;
        boolean conectado = true;
        //apuntandose a la lista de observadores del mensaje
        mensajes.addObserver(this);

        while(conectado) {
            try {

                //Lee el mensaje enviado por el cliente
                mensajeRecibido = entradaDatos.readUTF();
                //Pone el mensaje recibido en mensajes para que se notifique a los obervadores
                mensajes.setMensaje(mensajeRecibido);
            }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                conectado=false;
                //si hay un error de conexion se corta de cuajo
                try {
                    entradaDatos.close();
                    salidaDatos.close();
                }catch(IOException ex2) {
                    ex2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        try {
            //Envia el mensaje al cliente
            salidaDatos.writeUTF(arg.toString());

        }catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    package Servidor;

import java.util.Observable;

public class MensajesChat extends Observable{



    private String mensaje;

    public MensajesChat() {

    }

    public String getMensaje() {
        return mensaje;
    }


    public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje= mensaje;
        //Hay que indicar que el mensaje ha cambiado com el metodo de Observable setChanged()
        this.setChanged();
        //Despues hay que notificar el cambio a todos los objetos observadores
        //notifyObserver llama al metodo Update del observador
        this.notifyObservers(this.mensaje);
    }


}





    private SSLSocketFactory factory= (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    private SSLSocket socket;
    private MensajesChat mensajes;
    private DataInputStream entradaDatos;
    private DataOutputStream salidaDatos;

    public ConexionCliente(SSLSocket socket, MensajesChat mensajes) {
        this.socket=socket;
        this.mensajes= mensajes;



        try {
            entradaDatos = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            salidaDatos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    public void run() {
        String mensajeRecibido;
        boolean conectado = true;
        //apuntandose a la lista de observadores del mensaje
        mensajes.addObserver(this);

        while(conectado) {
            try {

                //Lee el mensaje enviado por el cliente
                mensajeRecibido = entradaDatos.readUTF();
                //Pone el mensaje recibido en mensajes para que se notifique a los obervadores
                mensajes.setMensaje(mensajeRecibido);
            }catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                conectado=false;
                //si hay un error de conexion se corta de cuajo
                try {
                    entradaDatos.close();
                    salidaDatos.close();
                }catch(IOException ex2) {
                    ex2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        try {
            //Envia el mensaje al cliente
            salidaDatos.writeUTF(arg.toString());

        }catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }




    public class ConexionServidor implements ActionListener {


    private SSLSocket socket;
    private JTextField tfMensaje;
    private String usuario;
    private DataOutputStream salidaDatos;


    public ConexionServidor(SSLSocket socket, JTextField tfMensaje, String usuario) {
        this.socket=socket;
        this.tfMensaje= tfMensaje;
        this.usuario= usuario;
        try {
            this.salidaDatos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         try {
                salidaDatos.writeUTF(usuario + ": " + tfMensaje.getText() );
                tfMensaje.setText("");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}





    public class ClienteChat extends JFrame{


    private SSLSocket socket;

    private int puerto;
    private String host;
    private String usuario;
    private JTextField textField;
    JTextArea textArea ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new ServidorChat();
                    ClienteChat frame = new ClienteChat();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ClienteChat() {
        super("Cliente chat");

            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","UsuarioAlmacenSSL");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","890123");

            getContentPane().setLayout(null);

            JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
            btnNewButton.setBounds(453, 319, 117, 29);
            getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

            textField = new JTextField();
            textField.setBounds(21, 319, 420, 26);
            getContentPane().add(textField);
            textField.setColumns(10);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            scrollPane.setBounds(21, 18, 549, 258);
            getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

            textArea = new JTextArea();
            scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
            textArea.setEnabled(false); // El area de mensajes del chat no se debe de poder editar
            textArea.setLineWrap(true); // Las lineas se parten al llegar al ancho del textArea
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true); // Las lineas se parten entre palabras (por los espacios blancos)

            VentanaConfiguracion vc = new VentanaConfiguracion(this);
            host = "localhost";
            puerto = 1234;
            usuario = vc.getUsuario();

            // Se crea el socket para conectar con el Sevidor del Chat
            try {
                SSLSocketFactory factory=(SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
            socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, puerto);
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Accion para el boton enviar
            btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ConexionServidor(socket, textField, usuario));



    }


      public void recibirMensajesServidor(){
            // Obtiene el flujo de entrada del socket
            DataInputStream entradaDatos = null;
            String mensaje;
            try {
                entradaDatos = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Bucle infinito que recibe mensajes del servidor
            boolean conectado = true;
            while (conectado) {
                try {
                    mensaje = entradaDatos.readUTF();
                    textArea.append(mensaje + System.lineSeparator());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    conectado = false;
                } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                   ex.printStackTrace();
                    conectado = false;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: *"The first problem appears in [...]"* - what problem?

Comment: Also, please consider a [mcve]. No one will want to crawl through all this code.

Comment: at cliente.ClienteChat.<init>(ClienteChat.java:83)

Comment: Sry im new in this...

Comment: See [ask] then.

Comment: You still did not state the error.